# buttons not showing in chrome but do in safari

Tags: google-chrome, web, safari

I have several buttons in the head section of the html page however, they don't seem to display on chrome whereas they do on safari.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>


 body{
        background-image: url("background_index.jpg");
     }
</style>

<head>

    <button style='font-family:Tahoma,Geneva,sans-serif;'><a href=""> Resume </a></button>
    <button style='font-family:Tahoma,Geneva,sans-serif;'><a href=""> Projects </a></button>
    <button style='font-family:Tahoma,Geneva,sans-serif;'><a href=""> Blogs </a></button>
    <button style='font-family:Tahoma,Geneva,sans-serif;'><a href=""> Contact info  </a></button>



    <h1 style='font-family:Impact, Charcoal,sans-serif;font-size:25px; text-align: center; position:relative; top:50px'> Welcome to my website. </h1>

</head>
<body>

<p1 style='position: absolute; top:200px; padding-left:100px'> Hello there </br> </p1>
<img src="self_pic.jpg" style="height:450px;width:30%; position:absolute; top:300px; padding-left:450px;"></img>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Are there any errors in the console? If so, please add them to your question.

Comment: no there are not